# Compiling string htmlusing angular compile not working having ng-repeat in it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-templates

*Sorry for bad question format before. Changing this now*

I have a html string which uses the ngrepeat to render the required div..

```
 var templateHTML = "<div ng-repeat='entity in createCtrl.finalCCList'>\
                         <span>{{entity.name}}</span>\
                     </div>";
```

Here **"createCtrl.finalCCList"** has list of entity object which has name and id properties in it.
Now when I try to compile this using -

```
var compiledTemplateHTML = $compile(templateHTML)($scope);
            if (compiledTemplateHTML && compiledTemplateHTML[0]) {
                return compiledTemplateHTML[0].outerHTML;
            }
            else {
                return "";
            }
```

I get nothing. Whereas i checked and $scope.createCtrl.finalCCList does have the required values.

Am I missing anything here.

Comment: Some code would be really appreciated in order to help you :) What you have done so far? What's your directive code? and html? How you use the directive?

Comment: @AsielLealCeldeiro updated now. Sorry about that.

Comment: it's still not really clear what you are trying to do here.  First of all, why are you trying to use `$compile`?  there are very few reasons to do this, and almost always a better way to structure your code.  Secondly, I don't think that `$compile` returns an array....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. After lot of research I figured issue was the DOM rendered by ng-repeat inside the string html after compiles takes time and I am assigning it before it complete. If i uses the assignment in timeout it works fine.

So instead of this-

```
var compiledTemplateHTML = $compile(templateHTML)($scope);
        if (compiledTemplateHTML && compiledTemplateHTML[0]) {
            return compiledTemplateHTML[0].outerHTML;
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
```

I am not returning but assigning to scope in $timeout

```
var compiledTemplateHTML = $compile(templateHTML)($scope);
        if (compiledTemplateHTML && compiledTemplateHTML[0]) {
            $timeout(function () {
                createCtrl.isHeaderContent = compiledTemplateHTML[0].outerHTML;
            }, 0);
        }
```

Thanks.